# Regex add leading zero to EAN-13

Tags: regex

Any suggestions on how to best use Regex for adding a leading zero to a 12 digit EAN-code.

EAN-codes are by default 13 digits (12+ 1 control), but some manufacturers use a 12 digit EAN, meaning you need to add a leading zero for it to work in some systems. How would I use regex to best do this?

If the code already has 13 digits, no alteration should be made.
(BTW, this is not due to a missing control digit - using a calculator to add the control to the 12 digits results in wrong barcode just fyi)

Thanks!

Comment: Why is Regex a necessary part of the solution to this problem? It seems like (check length of string. Prepend a 0 if length is 12) are a few lines of straightforward code in most languages.

Comment: I need to use regex due to the system that I am working on, data import for InDesign.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, another Dent in the Regex Universe added  here today..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regex, simply add a leading 0 to every 12-digits (and no more) EAN.

PHP example :

```
$ean = '978294019961'; 
echo preg_replace('/^\d{12}$/', '0$0', $ean); // 0978294019961

$ean = '0978294019961';
echo preg_replace('/^\d{12}$/', '0$0', $ean); // 0978294019961
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick when I removed the "/" 's.
Testing it with [myregextester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php).
Am not at ID machine currently, will test there soon..
Many thanks, it was an easy one!

Comment: `/` are delimiters, and `myregextester.com` automatically add them.

Comment: You can see, near the OPERATION dropdown, a DELIM dropdown, allowing you to choose which delimiter to use (default : `/`).

Comment: Ahh, ok now I understand what that means. Was looking at that thinking it has something to do with this..

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
String EAN13 = (EAN.length()==12?"0":"") + EAN;
```

PHP:

```
$ean13 = (strlen($ean)==12?"0":"") . $ean;
```

This is not using Regex, just plain pre-pending the ean with a zero, if the ean is 12 digits long.

Comment: Am not so familiar with the way this one is written.. InDesign addon uses simple Regex string for search and replace.

Comment: sorry, i assumed this was Java, but looking at the tags, you did not actually specify language...